# How to use next() function in Next JS API like Express JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

While making an API in Next JS, where I pass three parameter to my API function `(req, res, next)` here is the code :

```
import catchAsyncErrors from "../../../middleware/catchAsyncErrors.js";
import connectToMongo from "../../../middleware/db.js";
import isAuthenticatedUser from "../../../middleware/isAuthenticated";
import ErrorHandler from "../../../utils/errorHandler";

const handler = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    console.log(next); // Undefined
    if (req.method === "POST") {
      return next(new ErrorHandler("Not Allowed", 405));
      //     ^ Error
    } else {
      return res.status(500).send("INVALID REQUEST");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

export default connectToMongo(isAuthenticatedUser(handler));
```

I assure that ErrorHandler is working fine, but when I call this API it gives me the following Error:

```
TypeError: next is not a function
at eval (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/auth/test.js:19:20)
at eval (webpack-internal:///(api)/./middleware/catchAsyncErrors.js:3:25)
at eval (webpack-internal:///(api)/./middleware/isAuthenticated.js:22:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

In Express JS we pass next parameter to call next function or error handler but it seems like it doesn't work with Next JS. I am new in this framework so I need your help in this.

Comment: You're not showing what you're passing to `handler`

Comment: https://github.com/htunnicliff/next-api-middleware the problem is documented

Comment: @LeeTaylor thanks for your feedback , Its just a test api I am getting this error in all my api routes, I made this test api to fix the issue without messing with my code

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for the feedback, This is just a test api I am getting this error in all the api, I have tested ErrorHandler its working fine something is wrong with next() parameter.

Comment: Put a debugging breakpoint at that line and let us know the value of `next`

Comment: @LeeTaylor its says undefine, wait let me add full code for better understanding.

Comment: @RaghavPatel We were asking for more code earlier...

Comment: `next` doesn't exist in Next.js API routes. See https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction.

Comment: @jfriend00 I assure that `catchAsyncErrors()` is working fine there's no error init. I have tested it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

So I found that we cannot use next() function in next JS like we used to do in express JS. Next JS API function accept only two parameters `(req, res)`.

To use `next()` function to call other middleware, check out the bellow example :

```
import middleware1 from './middleware/func1';
import middleware2 from './middleware/func2';

const handler = async(req, res)=>{
//Your Code here
}

export default middleware1(middleware2(handler));
```

In the middleware functions:

middleware 1 :

```
const middleware1 = (handler) => {
return (req, res) =>{
//middleware function here
     return handler(req, res)
  }
}

export default middleware1;
```

middleware 2 :

```
const middleware2 = (handler) => {
return (req, res) =>{
//middleware function here
     return handler(req, res)
  }
}

export default middleware2;
```

As you can see both middleware take handler in parameter and return handler at end of code.
**Make sure to `return handler(req, res)` at the end of the function as given in code**